# What's the correct way to write our names?

Tags: abbreviations, writing, initialisms, surnames, subcontinental-english

Most people who live in my locality write their names with initials at the
end.  Usually these initials are abbreviations of long family names, like
*Joseph Alex **TP***, where *TP* stands for *Thevalliparambil* (a family
name here).

How should we write that "TP"?

1. Joseph Alex TP
2. Joseph Alex T.P
3. Joseph Alex Tp
4. Joseph Alex T.p

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This would be dependent on local conventions. Places where a particular name isn't common might not understand any abbreviation, and some places do not generally accept abbreviation of family names/surnames at all.

Comment: What about "Tp." with a dot after p? The possible problem with two dots or a dot inbetween (T.p.) is that this abbreviation convention commonly seems to imply separate words. However, ultimately conventions like this aren't always logical. For the Latin phrase *id est* we write "i.e." for example, but for *et cetera* we write "etc." with one dot.

Comment: It would take arrogance to correct a local custom not in English, and no choice offered is better than TP - Lord knows why periods would be included.

Comment: If the convention already exists and is understood then in the absence of a compelling reason to use a different convention, you should probably continue to use the existing convention.

Comment: Correct according to who? I'm not familiar with your locality (India?), but in the US, it would just be "T.", no second letter. A lot of names have no recognizable parts since they originate from non-English-speaking populations and even those that do (e.g. "Freeman") are given the same treatment anyway ("F.").

Comment: @Laurel - it's actually more likely in most of the US that the last name wouldn't be abbreviated, especially given that in many cases, abbreviations or letters after a name are not part of the name, but are indications of generational differentiation (e.g., Jr, III, etc.) or academic/professional/religious credentials (e.g., SJ (Society of Jesus [Jesuit order]), Ph.D., DDS, etc.).

Comment: Does anybody know a name like Franklin D. Roosevelt, which has two initials instead of one in the middle? Do such names exist in English speaking countries?  E.g. George W.X. Bush.

Comment: @HariS - It's not unknown; the 41st President of the United States, George Herbert Walker Bush, was often listed as "George H.W. Bush", and that became almost universal (to distinguish him from his son) when his son, George W. (Walker) Bush (without the Herbert) became the 43rd President of the United States.

Comment: George H. W. Bush (the other Bush)?  Note that his middle names are two separate names, one being a classic middle name and the other being his mother's maiden name. There are a lot of other examples, such as George R. R. Martin.

Comment: @Laurel - It also occurs to me that in the UK, similar initialisms may also represent social credentials (e.g., CMG, Companion in the Order of St. Michael and St. George).

Comment: Letters after a name could also represent a qualification such as John Smith D.D. (Doctor of Divinity).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is restricted to a small geographical area and the "correct" answer is to be found among the locals of that area.

Comment: @StuartF - Yes, that's what I was talking about when I mentioned initialisms standing for "academic/professional/religious credentials".

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about a local convention:

> Many people **in my locality**...
> **Usually** these initials are abbreviations of long **family names**

Outside the convention, it's uncertain whether the TP in the question would be understood as an abbreviation of a surname. Changing the convention is a moot question.

Within the area where that convention is understood, it's uncertain whether changing the convention means it will continue to be understood.

Consequently, if it's normally written as *Joseph Alex **TP**,* then that's what the convention expects.

If you choose to change that, I'd certainly suggest that the abbreviation be signalled with the full stop after it rather than in the middle, "Tp." instead of "T.p", but it's not something that can be answered outside the area where that convention is adopted.

We no longer have the "too localised" close reason, but this question is too localised.